# Display "Vacant" if a specific role designation is missing

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table with the following structure:

| role | designation | countries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR | Director | United States |
| HR | Advisor | United States |
| HR | Senior Executive | India |
| HR | Assistant | Argentina |
| HR | Assistant | United States |
| IT | Alternative Director | Japan |
| IT | Advisor | United Kingdom |

I want to create a query that displays "Vacant" for a specific role if the "Director" designation is missing.
For Example i given table In Role "IT" we don't have Director so I need to add a row with null counties and "Vacant" as designation.

Expected results:

| role | designation | countries | output designation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | Director | United States | Director |
| HR | Advisor | United States | Advisor |
| HR | Senior Executive | India | Senior Executive |
| HR | Assistant | Argentina | Assistant |
| HR | Assistant | United States | Assistant |
| IT | NULL | NULL | VACANT |
| IT | Alternative Director | Japan | Alternative Director |
| IT | Advisor | United Kingdom | Advisor |

Comment: you need to show expected result also, and show us the query  you are trying out and explain what is the problem with that query

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your current attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `union all` and conditional aggregation will get you your desired results.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  [role] varchar(2), 
  [designation] varchar(20), 
  [countries] varchar(14)
);
    
INSERT INTO Table1 ([role], [designation], [countries]) VALUES
('HR', 'Director', 'United States'),
('HR', 'Advisor', 'United States'),
('HR', 'Senior Executive', 'India'),
('HR', 'Assistant', 'Argentina'),
('HR', 'Assistant', 'United States'),
('IT', 'Alternative Director', 'Japan'),
('IT', 'Advisor', 'United Kingdom');
```

The query:

```
SELECT [role], [designation], [countries], [designation] as [output designation]
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT role, NULL, NULL, 'Vacant'
  FROM Table1 
  GROUP BY role
  HAVING SUM(IIF(designation = 'Director', 1, 0)) = 0
) 
ORDER BY role, designation
```

Results:

| role | designation | countries | output designation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | Advisor | United States | Advisor |
| HR | Assistant | Argentina | Assistant |
| HR | Assistant | United States | Assistant |
| HR | Director | United States | Director |
| HR | Senior Executive | India | Senior Executive |
| *IT* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *Vacant* |
| IT | Advisor | United Kingdom | Advisor |
| IT | Alternative Director | Japan | Alternative Director |

Comment: Glad to help :-)